# View allways get a fixed frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, frame, xib

I have a project target iOS 5 and above. I am not using Storyboard. I am using Nib file and sellect size for iPhone 5. But when I build on iPhone 6/6+/4. It allways return {0, 0} {320, 568} ?! Why? My XCode is 6.1.1

My LaunchImage:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the "size" from "Simulated metrics" ? The key word here is *simulated*, that is a set a convenience options to let you see how the view would look like if it was used as a full window view, but you still have full control over the actual view bounds.

Comment: I believe you need a launch image of the correct size for each model. Have you used an iPhone 5 launch image for the other phone types? I had this problem, but the opposite with the iPhone 5 looking like an iPhone 4 when run.